# Verifying client application identity - client is in the browser

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, security

I have back end written in PHP (actually I guess it doesn't matter).
I have client written in Javascript, which launches in the browser.

Application works in the following way:

1. User accesses url address and gets raw templates for rendering data
2. Via ajax, GET query is sent to back end server, querying for data for filling raw templates. Response is returned as valid JSON.

After these two requests happened, I can open console and resend the last ajax query.  I can copy all parameters and easily grab data from JSON.

I am not happy about such situation.
I want to find out somehow that query comes from by application.

I think of generation of some one time token on the back end. Giving it to the client on the step 1. Token can be used only one time. Client side after getting the token will use it immediately so making token useless for next queries. Tokens would have short live time because step 2 should immediately follow step 1.

So next time if ajax query is sent to the endpoint which returns essential information about product (step 2) - no data will be sent back in response.

I'm not looking for 100% guarantee that query has not been spoofed ( I feel it's kinda impossible though I 'd be happy to have such possibility). I look for some way to make it harder to spoof. Having the lock which works in 80% cases is better than to have no lock at all because it requires better qualification from breaker.

I have some doubts in the workability of approach I'm going to implement.

I need help with links how people do it usually or general ideas. Implementation is not a problem for me.  What I was able to  find 
 is "certificate pinning" though not sure  how it can help in my case.

Such problem has been solved before me by someone for sure. 
Do you know how? Any recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: So many `I`'s and `I'm`'s... All i can suggest is you add a CSRF token throughout, if the data is sensitive or you dont want it scraped then make them login.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm so so kind of not native. Is this kind of bad phrasing (where would  you recommend to  read about good phrasing)?   CSRF afaik works for form protection...

Comment: A rolling CSRF token "style" approach can be used to "allow" a subsequent request based upon the previous request, so set a token load your content, set a new one, send it as a header in the next and so on.. if you refresh the same request the token will be wrong..

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is called a "nonce" short for number used once. You can set it in javascript when you first load the page and add it to any request. You could store it in session on the server so you can validate that it is the same nonce as you expected. Each response from the server will need to include a new nonce and in your response handler you need to update the nonce set in your script.

If you have lots of requests that can be sent in parallel you can store an array of nonces and invalidate them on the server as you get them

Answer (score 1):

You can apply solution commonly used in mobile applications: sign your request with some hard to reproduce signature. add current time and random value to requested and add salt to signature. Put signature to HTTP header. Obfuscate your JS code.

Signature might be something like `md5("salt" + method + url + params + body + sessionId)`.

`params` should contain current time and random values among other parameters you need.
On backend calculate signature once more and reject requests without valid signature.